# TCP Client does not get reply for Socket.Send from Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, virtual-machine

I have a TCP Client which communicates over network to a Server running on a virtual machine, now the virtual machine has the guest operating system as IBM OS 4690 and the host operating system as Linux.

Occassionaly, the TCP server application running on the guest OS restarts. It seems to call the socket close correctly before restarting.

Once the restart happens, when the client tries to do a `Socket.Send`, it gets no response from the server.

If the server was running oh physical hardware, the client was able to detect a connection reset through TCP Error 10054. This does not appear when the server is running on the virtual machine.

Comment: Can you run tcpdump or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the client machine (perhaps you meant .NET `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send` ?) so that you can observe what is going on in more details?

Answer (score 0):

Your TCP client should be prepared that Send request will not be answered at all. Imagine a situation when TCP client sends data and server machine is suddenly restarted (or loses power). Client application will not get any TCP RST flag (error 10054).

For instance, you can add re-transmission logic your application protocol to handle such situations.
It can be something like this:

  - client Sends data

  - if no response for predefined time or connection closed - repeat request (data send).

  - if number of attempts exceeds some value (say 5), declare server unavailable.